# Dynamic removal of a column and row in a sparse matrix representation

Tags: matlab, row, sparse-matrix

I ve got a sparse representation of a square matrix in matlab. I am trying to perform eigen analysis calculating its eigen value and eigen vector n-1 times by  removing its time a row and a column.  My problem is how to perform the row and column removal. My code:

```
A = textread('matrices.txt');  %nx3 matrix
for k=1:n% size of the matrix
   display(k)
   temp = A;
   for index_i =1:length(temp)
      if(temp(index_i, 1)== k  | temp(index_i,2) == k)
          temp(index_i,:) = [];
      end
   end
   S = spconvert(temp); % sparse representation of the matrix
   [a b] = eigs(S); % calculate the first six eigenvalues and eigenvectors
   temp_vectors(:,k) =  a(:,1);
   temp_values(k) = b(1,1);
end
```

I ve got problem with indexing, in line  temp(index_i,:) = []; Basically You are right I did something different, however your implementation is better:

```
for k=1:10000 % size of the matrix
temp = A;
counter = 1;
list = [];
display(k)
for index_i =1:length(temp)
    if(temp(index_i, 1)== k  | temp(index_i,2) == k)
        list(counter) = index_i;
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end
temp(list(:),:)= [];
size(temp)
S = spconvert(temp); % sparse representation of the matrix
[a b] = eigs(S); % calculate the first six eigenvalues and eigenvectors
 %temp_vectors(:,k) =  a(:,1);
temp_values(k) = b(1,1);
name = strcat('eigen_vectors\eigen_vector_', int2str(k) ,'.mat');
vec = a(:,1);
save(name, 'vec');
```

end

Moreover, a new trouble arises. The problem stands in the calculation of the nth eigen analysis. I ve got to remove the 10.000th row and column in order to eigen analyze my matrix. However, by doing so it calculates a eigen vector of 9999 size since it deletes the 10000th row/column. Any idea to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `[]` to remove values, you are changing the size of the matrix. But in your inner loop you make `index_i` run up to the initial maximum size of `temp`. Therefore you are likely reaching a point where `index_i` is larger than the current size of the `temp`, and you will get a corresponding error.

Instead of using a loop to remove them one at a time, you can do this in one step with logical indexing:

```
temp(temp(:,1)==k|temp(:,2)==k,:)=[];
```